# Copy columns of a file to specific location of another pipe delimited file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file suppose xyz.dat which has data like below -

```
a1|b1|c1|d1|e1|f1|g1
a2|b2|c2|d2|e2|f2|g2
a3|b3|c3|d3|e3|f3|g3
```

Due to some requirement, I am making two new files(aka m.dat and o.dat) from original xyz.dat.
M.dat contains columns 2|4|6 like below after running some logic on it -

```
b11|d11|f11
b22|d22|f22
b33|d33|f33
```

O.dat contains all the columns except 2|4|6 like below without any change in it -

```
a1|c1|e1|g1
a2|c2|e2|g2
a3|c3|e3|g3
```

Now I want to merge both M and O file to create back the original format xyz.dat file.

```
a1|b11|c1|d11|e1|f11|g1
a2|b22|c2|d22|e2|f22|g2
a3|b33|c3|d33|e3|f33|g3
```

Please note column positions can change for another file. I will get the columns positions like in above example it is 2,4,6 so need some generic command to run in loop to merge the new M and O file or one command in which I can pass the columns positions and it will copy the columns form M.dat file and past it in O.dat file.

I tried paste, sed, cut but not able to make any perfect command.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you specify column positions as 2, 3, 6 ?. From the example (a1|b11\c1|d11|e1|f11|g1), looks like first file file columns are 2, 4 and 6

Comment: Sorry it is a typo.. It is 2,4,6 only.

Answer (score 1):

To perform column-wise merge of two files, better to use a scripting engine (Python, Awk or Perl or even bash). Tools like paste, sed and cut do not have enough flexibility for those tasks (join may come close, but require extra work).

Consider the following `awk` based script

```
awk -vOFS='|' '-F|' '
{
    getline s < "o.dat"
    n = split(s. a)
    # Print output, Add a[n], or $n, ... as needed based on actual number of fields.
    print $1, a[1], $2, a[2], $3, a[3], a[4]
}
' m.dat
```

The `print` line can be customized to generate whatever column order

Comment: have many files with multiple columns, here i have to first find columns count and then create the print command. is there any other better solution like in perl??

Comment: I did not realize there was requirement for N files. Question implies file get into 2. It will help if you post complete requirements and sample data in the question. It will allow SO readers to give you feedback to address you challenge.

Comment: I meant to say that I have many files for which I have to follow the same process. For Ex  - If I have abc.dat file and it has 10 columns then I might need to change 2 and 7 column and then merge it again other remaining 8 column.

Comment: @Mohit See alternative implementation, which take the list of columns for the merge as input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on clarification from OP, looks like the goal is: Given an input of two files, and list of columns where data should be merged from the 2nd file, produce an output file that contain the merge data.

For example:

```
   awk -f mergeCols COLS=2,4,6 M=b.dat a.dat

   # If file is marked executable (chmod +x mergeCols)
   mergeCols COLS=2,4,6 M=b.dat a.dat
```

Will insert the columns from b.dat into columns 2, 4 and 6, whereas other column will include data from a.dat

Implementation, using `awk`: (create a file mergeCols).

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
}
NR==1 {
    # Set the column map
    nc=split(COLS, c, ",")
    for (i=1 ; i<=nc ; i++ ) {
        cmap[c[i]] = i
    }
}
{
    # Read one line from merged file, split into tokens in 'a'
    getline s < M
    n = split(s, a)
    # Merge columns using pre-set 'cmap'
    k=0
    for (i=1 ; i<=NF+nc  ; i++ ) {
        # Pick up a column
        v = cmap[i] ? a[cmap[i]] : $(++k)
        sep = (i<NF+nc) ? "|" : "\n"
        printf "%s%s", v, sep
    }
}
```